# Draw a Sodoku Grid in C++

Tags: c++, grid

So I have been writing a program that will take a sodoku from an external text file, fill it into a 2 dimensional array, and then print the solved result. I have all the logic for solving the program finished, but whenever I output the sodoku into the console, it looks like this:

```
8 1 2 7 5 3 6 4 9
9 4 3 6 8 2 1 7 5
6 7 5 4 9 1 2 8 3
1 5 4 2 3 7 8 9 6
3 6 9 8 4 5 7 2 1
2 8 7 1 6 9 5 3 4
5 2 1 9 7 4 3 6 8
4 3 8 5 2 6 9 1 7
7 9 6 3 1 8 4 5 2
```

Now if my goal was simply to output the result, this would be perfectly fine, but I want something more easy to read and Sodoku-like.

Ideally I would like for their to be 3x3 squares around all of the necessary blocks in the Sodoku, and make it look something like this or at least something similar:

```
 ----- ------ ------
|8 1 2| 7 5 3| 6 4 9|
|9 4 3| 6 8 2| 1 7 5|
|6 7 5| 4 9 1| 2 8 3|
 ----- ------ ------
|1 5 4| 2 3 7| 8 9 6|
|3 6 9| 8 4 5| 7 2 1|
|2 8 7| 1 6 9| 5 3 4|
 ----- ------ ------
|5 2 1| 9 7 4| 3 6 8|
|4 3 8| 5 2 6| 9 1 7|
|7 9 6| 3 1 8| 4 5 2|
 ----- ------ ------
```

Here I will also include my print function for the sodoku itself:

```
void print_puzzle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            cout << puzzle[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me out with the specific implementation to achieve my goal that would be extremely helpful

**EDIT**

I have rewritten the print function of my code to where it outputs the sodoku as the following:

```
 ------  ------  ------
| 8 1 2 | 7 5 3 | 6 4 9 |
| 9 4 3 | 6 8 2 | 1 7 5 |
| 6 7 5 | 4 9 1 | 2 8 3 |
 ------  ------  ------
| 1 5 4 | 2 3 7 | 8 9 6 |
| 3 6 9 | 8 4 5 | 7 2 1 |
| 2 8 7 | 1 6 9 | 5 3 4 |
 ------  ------  ------
| 5 2 1 | 9 7 4 | 3 6 8 |
| 4 3 8 | 5 2 6 | 9 1 7 |
| 7 9 6 | 3 1 8 | 4 5 2 |
 ------  ------  ------
```

I have done so by editing my function to the following:

```
void printPuzzle()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || i == 3 || i == 6)
        {
            cout << " ------  ------  ------" << endl;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
        {
            if (j == 0 || j == 3 || j == 6)
            {
                cout << "| ";
            }
            cout << puzzle[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << "|";
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << " ------  ------  ------" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please try on your own first, SO is no code writing service ;) Here's how I would approach itt: Instead of 9 rows/columns you have 13 rows/cols but the first and every fourth subsequent row/col is not a number but a `-` or `|`.

Comment: Here's a simple way to figure out how to do this, and it never fails to work. Just take out a blank sheet of paper. Write down using short, simple sentences in plain English, a step-by-step process of doing this. When done, [call your rubber duck for an appointment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). We don't write code for other people, on Stackoverflow. We always refer such questions to your rubber duck. After your rubber duck approves your proposed plan of action, simply take what you've written down and translate it directly into C++. Mission accomplished!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: You were writing: "We don't write code for other people..." Who is we?

Comment: Well, @ArminMontigny, that would  me, the other commenter, and all the others who have stated the same.